# How to pass a switch parameter in a http trigger type of Azure function using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell

I want to use an Azure function to modify the backend pool of a load balancer that will be triggered from an HTTP api.

My functions needs input parameters so it can do validations and use the Az module to modify the Load balancer backend pool.

What i am struggling is that i do not know how to pass a switch parameter as i want the function to have 3 mini functions of removing/adding and setting the backend pool based on a switch parameter provided.

You can find parts of my code below. Thanks.

This is the beginning of the function run.ps1 file:

```
 param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
 $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    
 # Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
 Write-Host "Function processed a request."
    
 [string]$resourceGroupName = $Request.Query.resourceGroupName
 if (-not $resourceGroupName) { [string]$resourceGroupName = $Request.Body.resourceGroupName }
 [string]$vnetName = $Request.Query.vnetName
 if (-not $vnetName) { [string]$vnetName = $Request.Body.vnetName }
 [string]$loadBalancerName = $Request.Query.loadBalancerName
 if (-not $loadBalancerName) { [string]$loadBalancerName = $Request.Body.loadBalancerName }
 [string]$backendPoolName = $Request.Query.backendPoolName
 if (-not $backendPoolName) { [string]$backendPoolName = $Request.Body.backendPoolName }
 [array]$backendIps = $Request.Query.backendIps
 if (-not $backendIps) { [array]$backendIps = $Request.Body.backendIps }
 [switch]$Add = [switch]$Request.Query.Add
 if (-not [switch]$Add) { [switch]$Add = [switch]$Request.Body.Add }
 [switch]$Remove = $Request.Query.Remove
 if (-not $Remove) { [switch]$Remove = $Request.Body.Remove }
 [switch]$Set = $Request.Query.Set
 if (-not $Set) { [switch]$Set = $Request.Body.Set }
```

These are the contents of function.json:

```
 {
   "bindings": [
     {
       "authLevel": "function",
       "type": "httpTrigger",
       "direction": "in",
       "name": "Request",
       "methods": [
         "get",
         "post"
       ]
     },
     {
       "type": "http",
       "direction": "out",
       "name": "Response"
     }
   ]
 }
```

This is the call method:

```
$iwr = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:7071/api/modify-lb-backend-pool?resourceGroupName=$resourceGroupName&vnetName=$vnetName&loadBalancerName=$loadBalancerName&backendIps=$backendIps&backendPoolName=$backendPoolName&Set=$Set" -Method Get
```

And this the error i get:

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot convert the "void Add(string key, string value), void IDictionary[string,string].Add(string key, string value), void ICollection[KeyValuePair[string,string]].Add(System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[string,string] item), void IDictionary.Add(System.Object key, System.Object value)" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSMethod`1[[System.Management.Automation.MethodGroup`4[[System.Func`3[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Management.Automation.VOID, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Func`3[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Management.Automation.VOID, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Func`2[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Management.Automation.VOID, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Func`3[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Management.Automation.VOID, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]" to type "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter".
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.678Z] 
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.680Z] Exception             : 
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.681Z]     Type    : System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.683Z]     Message : Cannot convert the "void Add(string key, string value), void IDictionary[string,string].Add(string key, string value), void ICollection[KeyValuePair[string,string]].Add(System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[string,string] item), void IDictionary.Add(System.Object key, System.Object value)" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSMethod`1[[System.Management.Automation.MethodGroup`4[[System.Func`3[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Management.Automation.VOID, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Func`3[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Management.Automation.VOID, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Func`2[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Management.Automation.VOID, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Func`3[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Management.Automation.VOID, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]" to type "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter".
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.691Z]     HResult : -2146233087
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.692Z] CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.715Z] FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.718Z] InvocationInfo        : 
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.720Z]     ScriptLineNumber : 17
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.722Z]     OffsetInLine     : 1
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.724Z]     HistoryId        : -1
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.726Z]     ScriptName       : C:\Code\Azure Functions\backend-pool\modify-lb-backend-pool\run.ps1
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.728Z]     Line             : [switch]$Add = [switch]$Request.Query.Add
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.730Z] 
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.732Z]     PositionMessage  : At C:\Code\Azure Functions\backend-pool\modify-lb-backend-pool\run.ps1:17 char:1
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.735Z]                        + [switch]$Add = [switch]$Request.Query.Add
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.742Z]                        + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.745Z]     PSScriptRoot     : C:\Code\Azure Functions\backend-pool\modify-lb-backend-pool
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.747Z]     PSCommandPath    : C:\Code\Azure Functions\backend-pool\modify-lb-backend-pool\run.ps1
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.748Z]     CommandOrigin    : Internal
 [2021-07-21T12:06:48.754Z] ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Code\Azure Functions\backend-pool\modify-lb-backend-pool\run.ps1: line 17
```

Comment: The error means you are trying to convert the `$Request.Body.Add` **method** to a switch type. You seem to need a **property** `Add` on the `$Request.Body`. You should check the type of `$Request.Body`

Comment: Perhaps you want `$Request.Body['Add']` instead